# How do I specify a change address with monero-wallet-cli transfer?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, change

How do I specify a change address with `monero-wallet-cli transfer address amount`? Where can I find more information about `monero-wallet-cli transfer`? `monero-wallet-cli --help` does not give me anything to read about the command, it does not even seem to be listed there among other commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I specify a change address with monero-wallet-cli transfer address amount?

You don't, the wallet creates a new output (a change output), for you.

> monero-wallet-cli --help does not give me anything to read about the command

`--help` is a command line flag for help of the other command line flags. When you run the wallet (interactively), type `help transfer` to see the help for the transfer command. Or `help all` to see all available commands.

Comment: Is there a way to consolidate my UTXOs to one subaddress (other than to use `sweep_all`)?

Comment: Why do you want to "consolidate"? Outputs are owned by the wallet, regardless which subaddress they were sent to.

Comment: I want to manage my UTXOs in such a way in order to pay less with fees in the future.

Comment: So then sweep_all or sweep_single. Remember this though: Given tx fees are sub-cent and *reduce* with usage growth, consolidating over fears of fee increase is really unnecessary. The other downside with consolidation is locking change when you later spend. There's really no point in trying to be clever here.